# mysql select multiple tables - return results eventhough the other tables is empty

Tags: mysql, join, full-outer-join

```
select * from deliveries, remittance
```

table 'deliveries' has 10 records while table 'remittance' has none. This query returns no results. what I want is mysql to return the 10 records from table 'deliveries'. please help me.

this is a sample table

deliveries ->
  trans_number
  from
  to

remittance ->
  trans_number
  from
  to

Comment: Why do you select from two tables when you want the results from just one table? Just select from deliveries.

Comment: did you try some like this ? **select d.* , r.* from deliveries d, remittance r**

Comment: @Laurik table remittance has also data but sometimes no data. so i have to select them both to display their data

Comment: can you show the table scheme???

Comment: I think @AlexCoroza is looking for `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @Dwza i can't get it. haha.

Comment: @zzlalani inner join doesnt return any values. ill try full outer join

Comment: show the table scheme...

Comment: @zzlalani i got an error. i tried it like this. select * from deliveries full outer join remittance

Comment: @AlexCoroza the `FULL OUTER JOIN` will only show the matching records from both tables. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Comment: @AlexCoroza http://stackoverflow.com/a/4796911/829533, full outer join is not supported in mysql

Comment: @AlexCoroza but I'm still confuse about your requirements. I'm not sure what are you looking for, can you explain what is your requirements?

Comment: @zzlalani i want to select these two tables with query and return results eventhough the other table has no records yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like

```
select * from deliveries
left join remittance
on remittance.id = deliveries.remittance_id
```

It will bring all data from `deliveries` and matching data from `remittance`

**UPDATE:**

If you want to show records in any case if any table has records then you are looking for `FULL OUTER JOIN`

But since `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not supported in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) try this query

```
SELECT * FROM deliveries
LEFT JOIN remittance ON remittance.id = deliveries.remittance_id
UNION
SELECT * FROM deliveries
RIGHT JOIN remittance ON remittance.id = deliveries.remittance_id
```

Comment: sir i tried your answer and it worked. But what if table 'deliveries' has no records and then table 'remittance' has records.

Comment: i saw it from the link you that youve provided earlier. this query emulates full outer join, right? thanks a lot for your answer man.

Comment: sir i have another problem. Really, i have 3 tables to select. is it possible select them in 1 query? using your solution.

Comment: @AlexCoroza have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9226900/829533 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11410564/829533

Comment: also have a look at this and its example http://stackoverflow.com/a/17663157/829533

Answer (score 3):

You might need to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select deliveries.* 
from deliveries
left join remittance on ... -- put a join condition here.
```

This will return all the records from the `deliveries` table even if no matching rows found in the other table.

If you used `INNER JOIN` it won't return any rows, since the other table is empty. But it will give you only the rows from the `deliveries` which match the condition.

Comment: sir what if table 'remittance' has records and 'deliveries' has none. using the above query will return no results.

Comment: @AlexCoroza - Yes it won't return any rows, if you want to return the rows found in `remittance` in this case use `RIGHT JOIN` instead `select remittance.* 
from deliveries
right join remittance on ...` or switch the orders of the two tables: `select remittance.* 
from remittance
left join deliveries on ...`

Comment: @AlexCoroza - For more information about the differences between the join types see this article: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     select d.* , r.* from deliveries d , remittance r
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some criteria so that `mysql` can display the result for the tables..Like **Join**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM deliveries 
LEFT JOIN remittance 
ON remittance.id = deliveries.remittance_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select d.* from deliveries d left join remittance r
```